# Processes of ProcessBuilder are not writing some output files (Java)

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am running some .jar programs from a Java code. To do that, I use ProcessBuilder, as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jarFile, configFile);                    
Process p = pb.start();

finished = p.waitFor(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                        

// print the error output
if(finished){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    result = builder.toString();
    reader.close();

    status = p.exitValue();
}

else{
    p.destroyForcibly();
    result = "Error: maximum time (600 seconds) exceeded.";
}
```

The above code is within a foor bucle that selects different jar files (using the jarFile variable) at each iteration. Each one of the jar files writes some output files (note that these output files are different from the standard output / standard error of the program, they are other additional output files).

The problem is that, sometimes, some of the jar programs do not create its corresponding files. If I re-run the code several times, the processes that write their output files are different in each execution (which is very rare).

Could someone give me an indication on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what those jar files are doing. But are you checking the `result` and `status`? Making sure that there are no errors?

Comment: The jar programs do some computations, and write their outputs in several txt files. There are not errors in the executions (the programs finish with status != 0), that's the strange fact...

Comment: Status != 0 is an error.

Comment: Sorry, status == 0 (there are no errors).

Comment: Well, you still need to give us the source of those jar files. They may be ignoring an exception under certain circumstances. Just describing them won't help. Better reduce the whole problem into a [mcve]